# Need to display cached map on website

Tags: javascript, html, embed, geocoding, offline-caching

I'm using javascript, http, css, and php to make a user interface for a project I'm working on. As part of the interface, I need to display a marker on a map (of a known, smallish area) based on a latitude and longitude that update behind the scenes every so often. The catch is that I won't have access to internet when I need to demo the interface, so the map must be able to display from a previously downloaded file.

As an ideal example, it'd be nice to have something like [gmapcatcher](https://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/) embedded on the webpage, but I would like to be able to interact with it using javascript (and I don't think you can embed gmapcatcher anyway). Another thing to mention is that I don't care what company's map is being used (I don't need GoogleMaps or anything special) as long as it works.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: To clarify, I will have access to both the server and client as they are on two networked VMs, so this question isn't as counter-intuitive as it might seem up front.

Comment: Well, that is kind of a weird situation to not be able to demo an application that requires an internet connection in a case where you don't have one.

Comment: Yes it is, but to clarify I will be operating both the server and client within a network of VMs that I will have access to, so I don't actually need the "internet" for anything.